# Eclipse plugin - menu item visible/enable when selected objects from same parent object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, menuitem

I would like to enable menu item in Eclipse plugin development for selected objects when they are of same parent object instance( not class type ).
I tried 'propertyTester' option but it can be used for some string,boolean etc test, but how can I test all selected objects of same parent instance?
I am trying to hide menu option instead of giving an error message when user clicks on menu.

Comment: If you are using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point you could perhaps use the `dynamic` element to contribute menu items dynamically. You can then write code in the contribution item to look at the selections.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I am using "Open With" context menu (MenuItem). It is currently controlled by definitions(org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions extension point). But I would like to control it by dynamic way

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Show us the code / extension points you are using.